Ошибка SQL (1396): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
Не могу добавить права пользователю root на доступ с localhost (т.е. с самого сервера).

/* Ошибка SQL (1396): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost' */

Не пойму что за ерунда?
Сейчас права такие:

MySQL v5.7

Так а какие полномочия у root? Нажмите на него слева и посмотрите на полномочия справа. Может у него действительно нет прав на таблицу Users.

Вам надо ДОБАВИТЬ привилегии (это делает команда GRANT), или всё же создать новую учётную запись (что делает CREATE USER)? Если создать - а есть ли право на создание учётных записей и выдачу им привилегий у текущей учётной записи?

Все галки в разделе "глобальные разрешения" стоят. https://ibb.co/KrdgV1g https://ibb.co/jGP5Chg

Удалось добавить пользователя через mysql-консоль:
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxx';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

Почему в GUi клиенте (HeidiSQL) не работало, я не понял.
